# Get the edge pixels between 2 classes

Tags: numpy, array, rasterio

I am trying to get the edge (the pixels that are in the border of 2 classes). I have a raster with 3 different values, and I want to keep just the pixels that are in the contact between class 1 and class 2.

I need to use python, preferably with gdal/rasterio. I thought do an dilation with scipy of 1 pixel to these areas and then keep just the pixels commons in both dilations, but that doesn't work.

```
b5 = path/to/rasterband

with rasterio.open(b5) as src:
    B5 = src.read()

    B5[(B5 <= 1450) & (B5 > 0)] = 0
    B5[(B5 > 1450)] = 1
    #and then flip values to get "erodel"
    erodew = ndimage.grey_dilation(B5, size=(1,1, 1))
    #erodel = ndimage.grey_dilation(B5, size=(1,1, 1))

    waterland = erodew + erodel
```

I think that pixels where waterland values are 2, must be the line of pixels that I am looking for.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742098/border-edge-operations-on-numpy-arrays) doing what I need, but I don't figure out how to apply these with my raster arrays data.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

# make empty copy of array containing class values
borders = np.zeros_like(class_array, dtype=int)

# get the size of the input array in both dimensions
x_size, y_size = np.shape(borders)[0],np.shape(borders[1])

# iterate through each value
for i in range(x_size):
    for j in range(y_size):
        # select those which are in class 1
        if class_array[i,j] == 1:
            # get slice of all adjacent pixels
            slice = class_array[i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1]
            # check if any belong to class 2
            if np.any(slice == 2):
                # update borders array
                borders[i,j] = 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. It gets closer, but it doesn't make what I need. I eventually could solve it, I am going to post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could make it this way:

```
    b5 = r'path\to\my\3classes\raster.img'

with rasterio.open(b5) as src:
    B5 = src.read()

    B4 = B5.reshape(453, 484)
    #I reclass from 3 to 2 classes to get all the borders of the water
    B3 = np.where(B4 != 1, 0, B4)
    mask = ((B3 != 1)) #this is the mask for the water/non water raster
    mask2 = ((B4 != 1)) #this is the mask for the 3 classes (water, land and NoData)

    #Here I get the NoData edges
    struct = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, 2)
    erode = ndimage.binary_erosion(B3, struct)
    edges = mask ^ erode

    #Here I get the Land and NoData edges
    struct2 = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, 2)
    erode2 = ndimage.binary_erosion(B4, struct2)
    edges2 = mask2 ^ erode2

    #Now I just need to keep pixels of the land and nodata edges that are not in common with no data 
    edges3 = np.where((edges2 == 1) & (edges == 0), 1, 0)
```

Honestly, I am not fully understand how or why it's working, but it does... I am confused about edges2. 
Anyway, the idea is that I mix the water edges with land and no data edges and then just keep the pixels that I need based on the 2 previous classification.

this is "egdes" (borders of water, with both land and nodata):
[image]

this is "edges2" (Land and nodata borders... I guess):
[image]

This is "edges3" (only water/land border pixels):
[image]

And this is what I got when applied the method that lpdudley suggest me:
[image]